# difference between @TestFor and extends ControllerUnitTestCase

Tags: grails

I am using grails 2.2.4 and relatively new to it.  I'm trying to unit test my controllers and am confused between what I see in books and on the web.  Sometimes I see people writing their controller unit tests like this:

```
@TestFor(MyController)
@Mock([Domain1, Domain2])
class MyControllerUnitTests {
   void testOne() ...
}
```

and sometimes I see this:

```
class MyControllerUnitTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {
   public void setUp() ...
   public void tearDown() ...
}
```

What's the difference and is one better than the other for unit tests in 2.2.4?  They both seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of mixins for tests was introduced in Grails 2 while the other approach you mentioned had been used in older versions of Grails. Take a look at this note from the official Grails documentation:

> Grails 1.3.x and below used the grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase class hierarchy for testing in a JUnit 3 style. Grails 2.0.x and above deprecates these test harnesses in favour of mixins that can be applied to a range of different kinds of tests (JUnit 3, Junit 4, Spock etc.) without subclassing

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#testing

So you should use mixins for your unit tests in Grails 2.2.4. More about available mixins and unit testing in Grails in general here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#unitTesting